# Problem two screens changing from Windows 10 to Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, mouse, screen

I have just installed Ubuntu on a drive and configured dual boot, which seems to work as expected. Problem is that when I start Windows 11, which was the original OS, then I can move the mouse from the wright screen to the left by moving the mouse leftwards, and of course, the other way around. When I start Ubuntu, the screens are reversed so I have to move the mouse to the right to enter the screen to the left, which is a bit annoying. Is there any way to fix this, and if so, how can it be done?

Best regards

Ulf H.

Comment: System settimgs > screens. Adjust the relative positions accordingly.

Comment: Thank you so much! It was so easy - and now it works like a dream!

Comment: You're welcome. Posted as an answer because it seems it's a recurrent theme. You can later select to accept it and/or upvote it.

Answer (score 1):

Multiple screens relative positions can be easily adjusted at System Settings > Screens

[image]

Simply do as instructed:

> Drag displays to match your physical display setup. (...)